# What is the process of creating a custom branded moodle app?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

So the goal is to create a mobile app filled with courses and I'm looking to use moodle as the foundation of the app instead of starting from scratch.
I did some research and came across the "branded app", but it seems to be a paid service offered by moodle themselves. Is there a way I can do it myself? Or are there any other alternatives to changing the layout of the app without the need to hire someone? If so, kindly guide me to some resources that I can use that would help me in re-designing the layout. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a large list of applications for creating courses, one of the most famous is Moodle, as you mentioned, I also recommend blackboard, the basic thing to start with is that you must install it on a server, either local on your computer or buy a hosting for Integrate it usually the hosting already have the moodle tool and all you have to do is manage it so that you can customize it yourself or in case you want to do it on your local computer you can go to its official page and download it as well as installing a server local server either wamp or xampp

Answer (score 0):

You can for sure make it done by yourself, however if you never done this before, it would not be so simple, and can take some time to dig around. In general, you need to get the code from their reporitory
https://github.com/moodlehq/moodleapp, create your own branch, change all things you want, compile and (optionally) post it to the marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

Oppia mobile - https://digital-campus.org/oppiamobile/  supports pre-loading courses onto the mobile